# Google APIs Key Restrictions - Whitelist IP AND HTTP referrer

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, networking, google-cloud-platform

This may be the same question as [API key with IP restriction vs HTTP Referrer restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48465847/1571676)

My issue is that I'm using a wordpress plugin that allows you to provide one Google API key, but uses that key for both javascript (client-side) calls to Google that I would normally pair with a HTTP referrer restriction in the google API console AND server-side calls to Google APIs that I would normally pair with an IP restriction. Is there any way to tell Google to whitelist both an IP and HTTP referrer domain on a single key? I presume I may need to ask the plugin developer to separate that into 2 keys such that I can restrict one to the IP and the other by HTTP referrer.

Comment: No. You will need 2 separate keys.

Comment: You can also check the API key best practices on this documentation to learn more how you can create 2 separate keys with different restrictions: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey